# Why Button is still interactable even when condition is true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When `BuyCloth()` is executed, Condition itemIsBought is True, but button is still interactable why is that?

```
private bool itemIsBought;

public static int coinAmount;

[SerializeField] private Button btn;
```

```
private void Start()
}
 StartCoroutine(CheckUnlockCoroutine());
}
```

```
    public void BuyCloth()
    {
        itemIsBought = true;
        Debug.Log("" + itemIsBought);
    }
```

```
    IEnumerator CheckUnlockCoroutine()
    {       

        while (itemIsBought == false)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(.1f);

            
            
             if (coinAmount <= 100)
             {
                 btn.interactable = false;
             }
             else if (itemIsBought == true)
             {
                 btn.interactable = false;
                 
             }
            else
            {
                btn.interactable = true;
            }
        }
        

    }
```

I'm not sure what to do next?